# Identifying widgets in IPython.html.widgets.interactive

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook, interactive

My question is based on [this example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Beat%20Frequencies.ipynb) from the Interactive widgets documentation, which uses `IPython.html.widgets.interactive` to create an interactive widget for exploring audio beats. This is the call that creates the widget:

```
v = interactive(beat_freq, f1=(200.0,300.0), f2=(200.0,300.0))
```

`beat_freq` is defined thus:

```
def beat_freq(f1=220.0, f2=224.0):
    ...
```

I'm puzzled specifically by this line of code:

```
f1, f2 = v.children
```

How did the author know that the child widgets would be in the order `(f1, f2)`, as opposed to `(f2, f1)`? Is it just because that's their order in the call to interactive that created the widget? Or is it derived from their order in the call signature to beat_freq? What would happen if I added and removed widgets from `v` after it was created?

To be honest, I don't really care about the answers to those questions. I just want a way to identify the widget corresponding to each variable. I'm thinking there must be a way that one can figure this out by inspecting the `ContainerWidget` `v`, without having to know how it was created. After all, `v` itself obviously knows, since `v.kwargs` is a dict connecting variable names to values, and changes appropriately if you fiddle with the widget. Unfortunately, the docstrings in this module are minimal or nonexistent, and I haven't been able to work it out for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I have figured this out, mostly. The answer to the first question, what determines the order of the child widgets, seems to be that it is determined by the call signature of the handler function `beat_freq`. At least, if I reverse the order of the keyword parameters in the definition of `beat_freq` while leaving them the same in the call to `interactive`, the order of the child widgets is reversed: they are now `(f2, f1)`. What would happen if `beat_freq` were defined as `beat_freq(**kwargs)` I haven't explored. In any case, this seems sufficiently idiosyncratic to me that it ought not to be relied on.

The answer to the second question, how to identify the widget corresponding to each variable, is simpler and clearer. It is the `description` traitlet of the child widget. So, in the example, `v.children[0].description` is `u'f1'`. If I swap the arguments in the `beat_freq` definition, `v.children[0].description` is `u'f2'`. This, I submit, is the reliable way to identify widgets created by interactive.